# node.js can't get some data

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to build a simple web with express.
I use postman to post some data in mysql.
But when I tried to use sql query the data showed undefined.

Here's my code.

login.js

```
const db = require('./connection_db');

module.exports = function memberLogin(memberData) {
    let result = {};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM member_info WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [memberData.email, memberData.password], function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                result.status = "fail to login"
                result.err = "please try again later"
                reject(result);
                return;
            }
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

part of controller.js

```
const memberData = {
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            birthday: req.body.birthday
 }
    loginAction(memberData).then(rows => {
                if (check.checkNull(rows) === true) {
                    res.json({
                        result: {
                            status: "fail to login",
                            err: "please try again"
                        }
                    })
                } else if (check.checkNull(rows) === false) {
                    res.json({
                        result: {
                            status: "success",
                            loginMember: "welcome " + rows[0].name + " login！",
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

Comment: Can't tell what's happening from.what you have here.  Show more code and how you're hitting this code.  Also, plaintext passwords are a horrible idea, please stop doing that, even in practice it's a bad habit.

Comment: I just try to practice not for bussiness.Try to practice how to fit data in database and api

Comment: Where does `loginAction` function come from, what does it do? Who is calling `memberLogin` function. Please share proper code and explain where you are facing issue. Try to debug code your self first, before asking for help.